# How to Install Trendnet TPL-406E2K Powerline Adapter in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers

How can I Install a Trendnet TPL-406E2K Powerline Adapter in Ubuntu 14.04? Is it possible?
(I am brand new to Linux so please be gentle.)

Answer (score 0):

The Trendnet TPL-406E2K is not a device that you would need to install drivers for. It transmits a standard ethernet signal through your home's power grid. First you have to connect one end to your router. Then just plug the other end directly into the wall (not a power adapter), connect your ethernet cable, and you're done:

[image]

See additional information and download the official documentation and resources [here](http://www.trendnet.com/products/proddetail.asp?prod=130_TPL-406E2K).

Comment: I use this system for a windows 7 computer and it works fine but when I plug in the Ubuntu laptop it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't be... Check the support details [here](http://www.trendnet.com/support/supportdetail.asp?prod=130_TPL-406E2K). There is a User Guide and on page 24 it gives you some tips.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install it, just plug it in and it should work.

[image: Example]

However, they do have an "Optional management utility compatible with Windows® 8.1, 8, 7, Vista and XP", but unfortunately, not for other operating systems. You could try running it with `wine`, but chances are low it would work IMHO, and you shouldn't need it anyway.

Comment: The "Optional Management Utility" only does 

1. Create a customized encryption key for your Powerline network and apply it to multiple Powerline adapters at the same time.

2. View the Powerline adapters connected to your network (using the MAC address) and the approximate connection quality and speed
of each Powerline adapters.

3. View and upgrade Powerline adapter firmware.
  
Who would want to do any of those?